# How could I elegantly update the value inside array of hashes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

Currently I'm using $.each to update the values located in array of hashes.

I wonder if there is any elegant solution to achieve this too.

## update each x value with `Date.parse`

```
  $.each($scope.flights, function() {
      var current_flight_no =  this
      $.each(current_flight_no.data, function(){
        this.x = Date.parse(this.x);
      })
  });
```

## $scope.flights

```
    [{
            name: "JW100",
            data: [{
                name: "Vanilla",
                x: "2016-03-15",
                y: 3888
            }, {
                name: "Vanilla",
                x: "2016-03-21",
                y: 9048
            }, {
                name: "Vanilla",
                x: "2016-03-22",
                y: 7008
            }]
        }, {
            name: "GK12",
            data: [{
                name: "Jetstar",
                x: "2016-03-15",
                y: 3678
            }, {
                name: "Jetstar",
                x: "2016-03-20",
                y: 4478
            }, {
                name: "Jetstar",
                x: "2016-03-22",
                y: 6378
            }]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: if you use angular there is an angular.forEach function so you're not bind to jQuery. I guess you could use lambda from ES6 if you're not using old IE version. underscore has his own forEach function too.

Comment: What is and isn't "elegant" is opinion. If you have working code and are looking for suggestions on improving it, Code Review, also part of the same setup as stackoverflow, is the place to ask, not here, which is a place for borken ocde.

Comment: As already suggested, don't use `$.each`. It can be: `$scope.flights.forEach(obj => obj.data.forEach(item => item.x = Date.parse(item.x)) )`

Comment: have you decided on the solution? :)

Comment: @dfsq hi, why no $.each , any cons?

Answer (score 0):

I would use pure JavaScript here i.e.

```
$scope.flights.forEach(function(flight) {
  flight.data.forEach(function(item) {
    item.x = Date.parse(item.x);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "for", for example:

```
for(var x in $scope.flights){
    var data = $scope.flights[x].data
    for(var i in data){
        var flight = data[i];
        var dateString = flight.x;
        flight.x = Date.parse(dateString);
    }
}
```